# Follow-up emails disappear from Outlook inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an end user that has an issue where if they right-click -> Follow-up on an email within Outlook 2010, the email disappears from the inbox.

Any help please on where the email goes? Is there a setting to keep the email within the inbox?

Comment: I know this is a strange one, but does anyone have any idea? There are no Outlook Rules setup.